# How to describe a returned promise in a function annotation?

Tags: javascript, annotations, promise

When writing JavaScript code, I always annotate my functions [like described here](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler), something like:

```
/**
 * Add two values
 * @param {Number} a
 * @param {Number} b
 * @returns {Number} the sum of a and b
 */
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Now when I write an asynchronous function returning a Promise this would be:

```
/**
 * Add two values
 * @param {Number} a
 * @param {Number} b
 * @returns {Promise} the sum of a and b
 */
function add(a, b) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(a + b);
  });
}
```

But now the description of the return type (`Promise`) misses information on what type the Promise will return when resolved.

How to denote that the returned promise will resolve with a `Number`?

I would think `Promise.<Number>` is best (similar to `Array.<Number>`), but haven't found any common practice in this regard.

Comment: AFAIK there are no common conventions but I would use `Promise.<Number>` too I think.

Comment: Not sure about your actual code, but couldn't your promise be rejected as well? In that case, I would rather write something like `@return {Promise} Returns a promise that will either be resolved with ... or rejected with ...`. That seems to be how most projects document returned promises.

Comment: Yes, in general you will have to describe both resolved type as well as rejected types. The rejected type is typically a list with possible Errors. Could be described as something like `Promise.<Number, RangeError | TypeError>`. I think it is important to have an annotation style for describing promises (rather than in human readable text), so these types can be analyzed automatically by IDE's, compilers, validators, etc.

Comment: I like `Promise.<Number, RangeError | TypeError>`. Apparently, that's how Medium does it (in JSDoc) as well, according to https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/509#issuecomment-29186993

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is [generics](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#generics). While [jsdoc doesn't officially support it yet](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/567) it's the correct way to handle it.

The correct way is thus: `Promise.<number>`.

Documenting `Promise.<number, Error>` is pointless in my opinion since a promise always rejects with an error - otoh specifying specific errors can be useful, but might be overkill. Your promise is a boxed value on an eventual number. So the correct way is to document it as such.

Comment: Thanks, this kind of summarizes earlier comments, and I agree with your point about mentioning errors.

Comment: "a promise always rejects with an error" - this is not true. You can reject a promise with anything, just like you can throw anything in JS. And yes, there are libraries, that actually reject promises with non-`Error` objects.

Comment: @m01 that's a horrible thing to do :D However, we're just talking about type signatures - just like you _can_ pass "incorrect" types in JS but shouldn't.